# CSS - Phantom border

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a [little css exercise](https://codepen.io/jonny-b/pen/KKmENrx?editors=1100) and for some reason I have what appears to be background color leaking out around the boarders of the image. I've tried everything I can think of and I can't get rid of it. It seems like when I remove the background-color property on the inverted-corner class it goes away. Alternatively, removing the border from the inverted-corner class also makes it go away. Unfortunately, that also breaks the design. Any suggestions?

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: "Hahmlet", serif;
  /*  font-family: 'Spectral', serif; */
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 425px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  transform: rotate(12deg);
}

.admitOne {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: solid;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 71%;
  left: 61px;
}

.cinima {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 53px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 91px;
}

.lyon {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: solid;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 71%;
  top: 120px;
  left: 61px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}


/* Numbers */

.number {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 35%;
  top: 58px;
}

.left {
  left: -45px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.right {
  right: -45px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/* Corners */

.inverted-corner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(205, 34, 35);
  width: 425px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 15px;
  border-left: dotted 3px;
  border-right: dotted 3px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
}

.inverted-corner:before {
  background-image: url("https://assets.codepen.io/4091246/redpaper.png");
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 40%;
}

.top:before,
.top:after,
.bottom:before,
.bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: solid 15px lightgrey;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.top:before {
  top: -45px;
  left: -45px;
}

.top:after {
  top: -45px;
  right: -45px;
}

.bottom:before {
  bottom: -45px;
  left: -45px;
}

.bottom:after {
  bottom: -45px;
  right: -45px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hahmlet&family=Spectral&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inverted-corner">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="admitOne">ADMIT ONE</div>
        <div class="cinima">CINEMA</div>
        <div class="number left">081221</div>
        <div class="number right">081221</div>
        <div class="lyon">Lyon Movie Theaters</div>
      </div>
      <div class="top" />
      <div class="bottom" />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your inverted corner class: transform: translateZ(0px);

```css
body {
    font-family: "Hahmlet", serif;
    /*  font-family: 'Spectral', serif; */
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 425px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    transform: rotate(12deg);
}

.admitOne {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: solid;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 71%;
    left: 61px;
}

.cinima {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 50px;
    top: 53px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 91px;
}

.lyon {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: solid;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 71%;
    top: 120px;
    left: 61px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

/* Numbers */
.number {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid;
    font-size: 35px;
    width: 35%;
    top: 58px;
}

.left {
    left: -45px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.right {
    right: -45px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Corners */

.inverted-corner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(205, 34, 35);
    width: 425px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 15px;
    border-left: dotted 3px;
    border-right: dotted 3px;
    border-color: lightgrey;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}

.inverted-corner:before {
    background-image: url("https://assets.codepen.io/4091246/redpaper.png");
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 40%;
}

.top:before,
.top:after,
.bottom:before,
.bottom:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: solid 15px lightgrey;
        

border-radius: 35px;
}

.top:before {
    top: -45px;
    left: -45px;
}

.top:after {
    top: -45px;
    right: -45px;
}

.bottom:before {
    bottom: -45px;
    left: -45px;
}

.bottom:after {
    bottom: -45px;
    right: -45px;
}
html
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hahmlet&family=Spectral&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inverted-corner">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="admitOne">ADMIT ONE</div>
                <div class="cinima">CINEMA</div>
                <div class="number left">081221</div>
                <div class="number right">081221</div>
                <div class="lyon">Lyon Movie Theaters</div>
            </div>
            <div class="top" />
            <div class="bottom" />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I like this solution. What made you think of it? I'm not sure I fully grasp why it works.

Comment: It forces chrome/safari to move part of the rendering to your video hardware.  That fixes some alignment issues with subpixel alignment like you have here.

Answer (score 0):

the rotation causes artifacts of bgcolor pixels outside the border

try this style (with clipped bg and refactored border) for `inverted-corner`

```css
.inverted-corner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(205, 34, 35);
    background-clip: content-box;
    width: 425px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 15px solid lightgrey;
    border-left: 3px dotted rgb(205, 34, 35);
    border-right: 3px dotted rgb(205, 34, 35);
}
```